# jQuery not selecting option element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having some difficulty targeting the value of a selected `<option>` tag with jQuery.
The `<select>` element is generated with AJAX. Here is my following code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="">
    <option class="paginate_click active" id="1-page">1</option>
    <option class="paginate_click" id="2-page">2</option>
    <option class="paginate_click" id="3-page">3</option>
    <option class="paginate_click" id="4-page">4</option>
    <option class="paginate_click" id="5-page">5</option>
</select>
```

With following jQuery:

```
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$('#results').on('click', '.paginate_click', function(e) {
        j$("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="/assets/loader.gif" /></div>');
        var clicked_id = j$(this).attr("id").split("-");
        var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]);
        j$("#results").load("development_fetch.php", {'page': (page_num-1)}, function(response, status, xhr){
            if ( status == "success" ) {
                    alert("Do Stuff with results");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I click from an option, nothing is happening! Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
j$(function ($) {
    //use change event of the select instead of the click event of option
    $('#results').on('change', 'select', function (e) {
        //use the :selected filter to find the selected option element
        var $opt = $(this).find('option:selected');
        $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="/assets/loader.gif" /></div>');
        //use the selected option to find its id
        var clicked_id = $opt.attr("id").split("-");
        var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]);
        $("#results").load("development_fetch.php", {
            'page': (page_num - 1)
        }, function (response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "success") {
                alert("Do Stuff with results");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that's just what I needed to get it working. You're a legend mate!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Instead of `click` event bind `change` event to select tag and not to option tag.

Also you don't need to write a logic to get pag_num value. It is already there in `select` value.

```
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$('#results').on('change', '.form-control', function(e) {
        j$("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="/assets/loader.gif" /></div>');

       // read value of select tag which gives you selected option.
        var page_num = j$(this).val(); 
        j$("#results").load("development_fetch.php", {'page': (page_num-1)}, function(response, status, xhr){
            if ( status == "success" ) {
                    alert("Do Stuff with results");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/226/).

Note : I have commented ajax call and prepend image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#results').on('change', '.form-control', function(e) {
                    $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="/assets/loader.gif" /></div>');
                    var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-");
                    var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]);
                    $("#results").load("development_fetch.php", {'page': (page_num - 1)}, function(response, status, xhr) {
                        if (status == "success") {
                            alert("Do Stuff with results");
                        }
                    });
                });
```